# C# executes both try and catch

Tags: c#, bots

I've a question about the try catch function in C#. I'm using it in my discord bot but it executes both. So it will do the try AND the catch. Why is this? Did I write something wrong or missed a little thing?

Code:

```
private void RegisterKickCommand()
{
    commands.CreateCommand("kick")
        .Parameter("a", ParameterType.Unparsed)
            .Alias(new string[] { "k" }) //add alias
            .AddCheck((cm, u, ch) => u.ServerPermissions.KickMembers)
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage(e.GetArg("a"));
                if (e.Message.MentionedUsers.FirstOrDefault() == null)
                {
                    await e.Channel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " That's not a valid user!");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await e.Message.MentionedUsers.FirstOrDefault().Kick();
                        await e.Channel.SendMessage(e.GetArg("Kick") + " was kicked!");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        await e.Channel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " I do not have permission to kick that user!");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Well, of course! The code inside the `try` will execute until it reaches an exception, at which point it will start executing the `catch`.

Comment: You should read a little about try-catch. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: That's how try/catch work. :)

Answer (score 1):

So as comments already pointed out that is a correct behavior. It means that your `try` block throws an exception hence the program is processing the `catch` block as well.

One thing though is that your message is suggesting that the only reason the `catch` is executed is a lack of permission. That sounds like something expected, something that is possible within a logic of the program. In such case instead of try catch block is better to use a flow control like `if`, e.g.

```
if(e.Message.MentionedUsers.FirstOrDefault().HasKickPermission())
{
     // process kick
}
else
{
    // show message the processing is not allowed
}
```

The role of try catch is to handle something unexpected. Like e.g. `NullReferenceException` (which looks like may actually be the case in your code because this bit `e.Message.MentionedUsers.FirstOrDefault()` can return null).

Also, to better handle exceptions you should catch an instance of an exception, and handle it accordingly, like that:

```
try
{
    // your code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Handle the error. E.g. Log it or display a message to the user.
    await e.Channel.SendMessage("Unexpected exception: " + ex.Message);
}
```